# I'm tryting to crawl a website. But I have some error in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I'm trying to crawl a website. But I have trouble....

While I am trying to crawl some element of a website. There are some errors...

```
     File "/Users/iab/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 430, in find_element_by_css_selector
    return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
  File "/Users/iab/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 659, in find_element
    {"using": by, "value": value})['value']
  File "/Users/iab/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Users/iab/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/iab/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

I think my source code isn't wrong. But when I run my code after 5min, these errors occur.

Comment: This is a good error, my bet is the code error is on line 43 probably

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducable sample of your code.. How is anyone supposed to be able to find the error in your code without it?